# How do you find the intercepted arc angle of two intersecting chords when chord length isn't known but the angle between them is?

Tags: geometry

I am working on an engineering problem that requires finding a general solution for the intercepted arc angle of these two chords bellow.

[Two intersecting chords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHnV7.png)

The radius ($r$) is known. The distance from the center to the chords intersect ($d$) is known. $\angle ASB$ and thus the other interior angles are known. For this purpose, $\overline{BD}$ can be assumed to always be the length of the diameter.

Is there a formula using only these values and values that could be derived from them to find the angle measure of $\overset{ \huge\frown}{AB}$? Most of the formulas I can find require me to already know $\overline{AS}$ or $\overline{SC}$, have the chords intersect at the center, or have the chords intersect on the edge of the circle.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us focus on $\Delta ASM$. Let $\angle ABS$ be $x$. We know the values of  $\angle ASM$, $AM$ and $SM$. Using the law of sines we get:
$$\frac {AM}{\sin\angle ASM}=\frac {SM}{\sin\angle MAS}$$
$$\frac r{\sin x}=\frac d{\sin \theta}$$
$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\biggr(\frac {d\sin x}r\biggr)$$

Now that you know two angles of the triangle, you can find the angle $\angle AMB$ which subtends the required chord. Here onwards it is really easy.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like exactly what I need. I'll test it out on my model on Monday.

Comment: Glad I could help :)